# Focus skipping cells in custom CollectionViewLayout?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, tvos

I am currently working on a tvOS app where I'm trying to display events in a time grid using a custom UICollectionViewLayout. I've hit a bit of a roadblock, and I'm hoping someone here can give me a hint to get me back on track :)

The issue I'm facing is related to the focus management within my UICollectionView. When I swipe left or right, I notice that several cells are being skipped, and the focus isn't behaving as expected.

Here is my code for reference:

```swift
// MARK: - CollectionViewLayout Class
class CollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
  // Constants for layout
  let CollectionViewLayoutHourViewWidth: CGFloat = 360
  let CollectionViewLayoutTopPadding: CGFloat = 56
  let CollectionViewLayoutBottomPadding: CGFloat = 10
  let CollectionViewLayoutTimeLinePadding: CGFloat = 6

  // Arrays to hold cell and hour attributes
  private var cellAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
  private var hourAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

  // Content dimensions
  var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0
  var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

  override init() {
    super.init()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  // Calculate and return the content size of the collection view
  override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(
      CollectionViewLayoutHourViewWidth * 24 + CollectionViewLayoutTimeLinePadding,
      self.collectionView?.bounds.size.height ?? 0)
  }

  // Determine whether the layout should be invalidated when bounds change
  override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  // Return layout attributes for a specific item
  override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
  {
    return cellAttributes.first { $0.indexPath == indexPath }
  }

  // Return layout attributes for all items within a given rectangle
  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
  {
    var allAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

    for attributes in cellAttributes + hourAttributes {
      if rect.intersects(attributes.frame) {
        allAttributes.append(attributes)
      }
    }

    return allAttributes
  }

  // Prepare the layout, calculate and set attributes for cells and hours
  override func prepare() {
    cellAttributes.removeAll()
    hourAttributes.removeAll()

    if let collectionViewLayoutDelegate = collectionView?.delegate as? CollectionViewLayoutDelegate
    {
      // MARK: - Event Cells
      for section in 0..<collectionView!.numberOfSections {
        for item in 0..<collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
          let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
          let timespan = collectionViewLayoutDelegate.collectionViewLayout(
            self, timespanForItemAt: indexPath)
          let posX =
            CGFloat(timespan.location) / 3600.0 * CollectionViewLayoutHourViewWidth
            + CollectionViewLayoutTimeLinePadding

          // Calculate the width based on the duration of the event
          let durationInHours = CGFloat(timespan.length) / 3600.0
          let width = durationInHours * CollectionViewLayoutHourViewWidth

          let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
          var attributesFrame = attributes.frame
          attributesFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: posX, y: CollectionViewLayoutTopPadding)
          attributesFrame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: 60)
          attributes.frame = attributesFrame
          cellAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
      }
    }

    // MARK: - Hour Cells
    for i in 0..<24 {
      let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(
        forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "hour", with: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
      var attributesFrame = CGRect.zero
      attributesFrame.size = CGSize(
        width: CollectionViewLayoutHourViewWidth, height: collectionView!.bounds.size.height)
      if i == 23 {
        attributesFrame.size.height += CollectionViewLayoutTimeLinePadding
      }
      attributesFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * CollectionViewLayoutHourViewWidth, y: 0)
      attributes.frame = attributesFrame
      hourAttributes.append(attributes)
    }
  }
}

// MARK: - CollectionViewLayoutDelegate Protocol
protocol CollectionViewLayoutDelegate: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionViewLayout(
    _ collectionViewLayout: CollectionViewLayout, timespanForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
  ) -> NSRange
}

// MARK: - Event class
class Event {
  let title: String
  let timespan: NSRange

  init(title: String, timespan: NSRange) {
    self.title = title
    self.timespan = timespan
  }
}

// MARK: - EventViewCell Class
class EventViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  // UI elements
  private var leftBorderView: UIView!
  private var label: UILabel!

  // Property to set the event data
  var event: Event? {
    didSet {
      if let event = event {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor("#232323")
        self.label.text = event.title
        self.label.textColor = .white
        setNeedsLayout()
      }
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // Create and configure the left border view
    leftBorderView = UIView()
    contentView.addSubview(leftBorderView)

    // Create and configure the label for event title
    label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    contentView.addSubview(label)

    // Add constraints for subviews
    leftBorderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      leftBorderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      leftBorderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
      leftBorderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
      leftBorderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4),

      label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftBorderView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
      label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
      label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
      label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
    ])
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  // Layout subviews within the cell
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    leftBorderView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 4, height: bounds.size.height)
    let labelSize = label.sizeThatFits(
      CGSize(width: bounds.size.width - 10.0, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: labelSize.width, height: labelSize.height)
  }

  // Handle focus update animations
  override func didUpdateFocus(
    in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator
  ) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

    let focused = context.nextFocusedView == self

    layoutIfNeeded()

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations(
      {
        if focused {
          // Apply focus styling
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor("#f96522")

          self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
          self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
          self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
          self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
          self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        } else {
          // Reset styling when not focused
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor("#232323")
          self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
          self.layer.shadowColor = nil
          self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
          self.layer.shadowRadius = 0
          self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        }

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
      }, completion: nil)
  }

  // Allow the cell to become focused
  override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
  }
}

// MARK: - ViewController Class
class ViewController: UIViewController, CollectionViewLayoutDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  private var events: [Event] = []

  private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create a custom layout
    let layout = CollectionViewLayout()

    // Initialize the collection view
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    // Configure collection view properties
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
    collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
    collectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor("#1a1a1a")

    // Add the collection view to the view hierarchy
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    // Set the constraints for the collection view
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
      .isActive = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    // Create and populate the events array (for now using sample data)
    events = [
      Event(title: "Banana Sunshine", timespan: NSRange(location: 18000, length: 1800)),
      // ...
      Event(title: "Celestial Symphony", timespan: NSRange(location: 82200, length: 4140)),
    ]

    // Register cell and supplementary view classes
    collectionView.register(EventViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")
    collectionView.register(
      HourReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "hour", withReuseIdentifier: "HourView")

    self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
    self.updateFocusIfNeeded()
  }

  // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource methods
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)
    -> Int
  {
    return events.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UICollectionViewCell
  {
    let cell =
      collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath)
      as! EventViewCell
    let event = events[indexPath.item]
    cell.event = event
    return cell
  }

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate methods
  func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
    at indexPath: IndexPath
  ) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == "hour" {
      let view =
        collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(
          ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HourView", for: indexPath) as! HourReusableView

      let hour = indexPath.item
      let timeLabel = String(format: "%02d:00", hour)
      view.time = timeLabel

      return view
    }

    return UICollectionReusableView()
  }

  // MARK: - CollectionViewLayoutDelegate methods
  func collectionViewLayout(
    _ collectionViewLayout: CollectionViewLayout, timespanForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
  ) -> NSRange {
    return events[indexPath.item].timespan
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let event = events[indexPath.item]
    // Perform action here with the selected event, for now just print it's title
    print("Selected event: \(event.title)")
  }
}
```

I already tried everything I could find online. That includes the usual delegate methods that have to do with the focus as well as using a UIFocusGuide which wasn't successful either. From some experiments I did with my code I must assume that tvOS has some weird requirements on collection view cells having a certain minimum width and the spacing between two cells can't be too narrow nor too small?

If anyone has experience with custom UICollectionViewLayouts on tvOS or has encountered a similar problem before, I would be incredibly grateful for any advice, tips or suggestions you can offer.